# Space station with sentient spiders

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I saw a film a few years ago. They had a spaceship and went to their spaceship station where these spider type things were on board where they later found out.

They leave and blow up the station and then get a call to check out another spaceship which had a distress call. It was completely abandoned with it actually becoming their mothership.

There was one scene where the spider jabbed one of the soldiers and the soldier was used as a talking device tangling from one the of spiders legs. Eventually i believe the spaceship crashed and they won.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 7):

This sounds similar to the [*Lost In Space*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120738/) movie.

The Jupiter 2 craft docks with a large ship, and while examining it find a race of spider like aliens, they do battle with them and escape, remotely self destructing the ship. The force of the blast sends them crashing down to a planet where they encounter a future version of the crew, one of which was transformed by a spider bite in to a large spider humanoid alien.

Comment: Thank you for giving an idea, however that is not the film i am looking for. I've always remembered it very similiar to Halo: Reach story. As the soldiers are quite similiar and along with the spaceship outline of events. Excluding the fact its only in space not on the ground.

Comment: Just from reading your question I thought it was lost in space too. Drat!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe Starship troopers Invasion 2012

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers:_Invasion

Comment: Oh my god yes fantastic! I've been trying to remember this film for years! Thank you very much.

Comment: Good.  Just give click on the checkmark. And your welcome